# Bundler loaded gem order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paperclip, bundler

I'm working on a small gem that will extend the paperclips has_attached_file method. I need this gem to be loaded after paperclip.

Is there a way to know the order in which the gems are loaded? And is there a way to modify that order?

Thanks a lot,

NHI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a Railtie to make this work. Paperclip was loading before my gem but wasn't include until much later...

Answer (score 1):

In your gemspec require the other gem then it should load before yours.
See the [docs](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#dependencies) for more information.

Comment: I have that dependency, but it's not working. My methods seems to get overwritten by paperclip's one =/

Answer (score 1):

i guess this might help give it a try.

```
gem 'New-Gem','some-version', :require => 'paperclip'
```